# Require statement usage in ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between these two sample Ruby programs? It seems the same. `require` just includes the Ruby program on memory.

require_sample1.rb

```
class Klass
  require "./effective_module"
  include Mod
end
```

require_sample2.rb

```
require "./effective_module"
class Klass
  include Mod
end
```

effective_module.rb

```
module Mod
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the sample code you've given, the behavior is effectively the same. However, it won't always be the same. For example, take the following code:

**effective_module.rb**

```
module Foo; end
```

**require_sample.rb**

```
require "./effective_module"
class Foo
end
```

When you run `ruby require_sample.rb` you'll get the following error:

```
require_sample.rb:2:in `<main>': Foo is not a class (TypeError)
```

This demonstrates to us that on line 2, when `class Foo` is reached, `Foo` has already been defined (by `effective_module.rb`) as a module, and Ruby won't let you redefine a module as a class.

Now suppose we make the following change:

**require_sample.rb**

```
class Foo
  require "./effective_module"
end
```

Now when you run `ruby require_sample.rb`, you get a different error:

```
.../effective_module.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': Foo is not a module (TypeError)
```

This time `Foo` is already defined as a `class` when the `require` is reached. Ruby won't let you redefine a module as a class.

Obviously this isn't the kind of code you'd write in the real world, but hopefully it helps demonstrate that where you put your `require`s *does* matter.

Comment: I thought placement of require might also affect the name spaces. I.e. if I `require` a file containing the `Foo` class inside the `Bar` class I would have to write `Bar::Foo.new` to create a new `Foo` object. I did an experiment, however, and it turns out that that's not the case; I can still just use `Foo.new`. I don't have a very precise question, but I'm a little confused. Maybe someone can explain why this is natural choice of behavior for ruby.